# Is it possible to start workflows via JSOM in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, jsom, workflow-manager

I'm currently trying to start a list workflow via JSOM. The problem is that every time I receive the following error:

> Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object
>   returned by the following call stack is null.
>   "GetWorkflowInteropService new
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager() "

I'm using a code similar to this one:

```
function fire2010WorkflowForListItems(ctx, listGuid, plainItems) {
    var workflowServicesManager =
        SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx,
            ctx.get_web());
    var service = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInteropService();
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; plainItems.length; i++) {
        var plainItem = plainItems[i];
        console.log('scheduling workflow for id: ', plainItem.id);
        service.startWorkflow(options.workflowName, null,
            listGuid, plainItem.guid, options.initiationParams);
    }
    console.log('now executing...');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        console.info('yes, workflows completed for '
            + items.length + ' items');
    }, function() {
        console.error('it didnt go well');
    });
}
```

found here:
https://chuvash.eu/2016/05/19/trigger-sp2010-workflows-using-jsom/

I've found, as well, this question, with a similar problem:
[(Solved) Start a Workflow of the Host-Web via SharePoint App and JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87015/solved-start-a-workflow-of-the-host-web-via-sharepoint-app-and-jsom)

The user solved it, partially, by going to Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage service applications -> Workflow Service Application Proxy.
Unfortunately, I can't find that option in my Central Administration.

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013.

In that case, my question is:
Do I need Workflow Manager 1.0 in order to start workflows from JSOM?
Is Workflow Manager available for Foundation? Or do I need the Server version?
From these two results my main question:
**Is it possible to start a workflow, from JSOM, while having SharePoint Foundation 2013?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is it possible to start a workflow, from JSOM?**

- Yes, it's possible.

**Do I need Workflow Manager in order to start workflows from JSOM?**

- Yes, Workflow Manager is a mandatory prerequisite to be able to Start workflow via JSOM. otherwise, you will get **Null object** when executing `SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager`

**Is Workflow Manager available for Foundation?**

- Unfortunately, Workflow Manager is not available at SharePoint Foundation.

**Or do I need the Server version?**

- Yes, Workflow Manager is only available in both Standard and Enterprise Edition.